# Hostname verification failed in OpenShift when integration a external service using an External Domain Name

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

I want to call a REST service running outside OpenShift via a Service and external domain name. This works perfect with a http:// request. The mechanism is described in the documentation : https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html#saas-define-service-using-fqdn

However the external service is secured with https. In this case I got the following exception: 
Host name 'external-test-service' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=GR, C=CH); nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'external-test-service' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.xxx, O=xxx, L=xxx, ST=GR, C=CH)

The exception is clear to me because we use the Service name from OpenShift. This name does not correspond to the origin host name in the certificate. So currently I see three possibilities to solve this issue:

1. Add the name of the OpenShift Service to the certificate
2. Deactivate hostname verification before calling the external REST service
3. Configure OpenShift (don't know this is possible)

Has anybody solve this or a similar issue?

Currently I used OpenShift v3.9. We are running a simple Spring Boot application in a pod accessing REST services outside OpenShift.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thank you

Markus

Answer (score 1):

1. Ugly and might cost you extra $$
2. Defeats the purpose of TLS.
3. On Kubernetes 1.10 and earlier you can use [ExternalName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname).

   You can also use with [OpenShift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html#mysql-define-service-using-fqdn).
4. You can also use and [Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) with [TLS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls). Also, documented for [OpenShift](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/openshift)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you're response. But we are using already ExternalName feature. That is the problem. The certificate from the external services is available as keystore in our Spring Boot application. We configured a Service with ExternalName type. This works perfectly with http://... When we use https:// in our application as URL for the external service we got the exception concerning the hostname. So from my perspective the error will be thrown by the Spring Boot application before the service name can be mapping to the real hostname.

Comment: Have you tried a L7 ingress with TLS? I added it to the answer.

Comment: Hi, we didn't try it with Ingress. However Ingress will be used to expose services running within the OpenShift cluster. However we want to use a service that runs outside OpenShift with the Service Layer from OpenShift.

Comment: Seems convoluted.  You could just terminate SSL on that Service Layer whatever it is and use self-signed certs inside.